# HTML Div size inherited from HTML tag, 100%

Tags: html, css

having trouble making division 100% of HTML size. It makes 100% of window size, but even if HTML is bigger than window it wont inherit its size, trouble with this all is that I only need one division to be as big as body or HTML is. My css for these are:

```
body, html{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;

    }

#leftNav{
    background-image: url("images/nav_bar.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left; 
    width: 20%;
    height: inherit;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background-color: #000000;
    }
```

this is how it looks at the moment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgoJA.png

This is how I want it to be: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWjdK.png

I dont want the rest of the content to be same size as HTML, just leftNav. Any ideas?

Comment: Is JavaScript an option, because it's quite trivial if it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
position: fixed;
```

to #leftNav.
Also, I'm pretty sure the width and height for body and html are redundant, and may possibly even screw something up..

Let me know if this isn't what you're looking for..

Comment: That is indeed an option, had to adjust rest content margin not to overlap with leftNav, but it does the job =] thanks, completely forgot about fixed position.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to scroll you will need to set a fixed width and/or height depending on whether or not you want it to scroll horizontally and/or vertically. The parent of body and HTML is the window so setting it to 100% will mean it is always the full width and height of the window.